# SharePoint 2010 Tabs

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to add "Tabs" on each of my SharePoint pages. I have full admin rights and have tried to add tabs, but can't seem to figure it out. I need help, can anyone assist?

Comment: Tabs being what exactly? Global navigation links? Subsites? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to add global navigation at the top of the page, the process is slightly different depending upon whether you have the publishing features enabled for a site or not.

If you don't have publishing enabled (the default):

1. Log in as a site collection admin
2. Select 'Site Actions' -> 'Site Settings'
3. Select 'Top link bar' from the 'Look and Feel' section
4. Select 'New Navigation Link' at the top of the content area:
   [image: New Navigation Link]
5. Enter the URL that the link should go to and the description that should be shown on the link
6. Once you have more than one link in the top link bar area you will also see a link to change the order.

If you have publishing enabled:

1. Log in as a site collection admin
2. Select 'Site Actions' -> 'Site Settings'
3. Select 'Navigation' from the 'Look and Feel' section
4. This give you much more control over how navigation items are displayed. E.g. you can an select to show the navigation items below the current site (including sites and pages) in the global navigation, subsites and pages on the local navigation etc.
5. Further down the page is the section titled 'Navigation Editing and Sorting'. Here's where you create and order navigation items. Use the controls to add headings and links, move and delete items:
   [image: Navigation Editing and Sorting]

Remember to click OK at the bottom of the page to save your changes!